# it possible use a nodejs package inside meteor app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

it posible use a nodejs package inside meteor app on server side? It would be great to do that since nodejs has a large number of packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2013 Meteor NPM Packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use an **npm** module in Meteor, since it's based on Node.js.

This code has worked for me fine, e.g.:

```
var fs = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('fs');
```

**UPDATE: To install an npm module in a Meteor app**

1. Inside your terminal, change path to your Meteor app directory.
2. `> cd .meteor/local/build/server`
3. Install an npm module like so `> npm install module_name`.

---

**Edit:** for anyone visiting this post, it is outdated. As of Meteor 0.6.4, you use `Npm.require` instead of `__meteor_bootstrap__.require`:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

Also, if you don't use standard node package, but one from npm repositories, it's better to create a dependency so that it's automatically installed every time you create a new instance of the project. To do so, create a `/packages/someName/package.js` file with the following line:

```
Npm.depends({'packageName': 'packageVersion'});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but how could I install nodejs packages inside a meteor app?

Comment: Sorry I should've included this information in the first place. I've now updated my answer with the relevant info. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Any idea on how to make modules with transitive dependencies work? Like aws-lib for example?

Comment: This answer is incorrect... `Npm.depends()` is [only for use in a `package.js` file](http://docs.meteor.com/#Npm-depends). Use the [meteorhacks:npm package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) to be able to use npm modules in Meteor apps.