# Meteor.js and LDAP

Tags: node.js, ldap, meteor

Any chance that LDAP authentication will be integrated into Meteor.js in the near future?

Any hints on how to get this to work today?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever working with meteor, I would suggest looking at resources that are available for node.js, when and if something isn't in the meteor docs, and there isn't already a relevant discussion here.

The reason this seems like a good start would be that meteor runs inside a node.js server instance inside a fiber. At the very least existing node.js modules may help you understand where to go next.

By performing a cursory google search for `nodejs ldap`, I had discovered a couple of very useful resources:

http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/09/08/ldapjs-a-reprise-of-ldap/
http://ldapjs.org/

Finally, you will likely need the answer to this question to get you on your way:
[it possible use a nodejs package inside meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691513/it-possible-use-a-nodejs-package-inside-meteor-app)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2015 the best available package is https://atmospherejs.com/typ/accounts-ldap

```
meteor add typ:accounts-ldap
```

I used this package in a few projects and from my experience it always requires the `dn` to authenticate. If you want to use the email instead, you would first have to find the `dn` with a separate query (ideally your LDAP offers you some sort of resolver / API to query the `dn` by email).

On the server side, you configure the following default (any file exposed to the server):

```
LDAP_DEFAULTS.url = 'ldap://my-ldap-host.com'
```

On the client side, you can then call:

```
Meteor.loginWithLDAP(login, password, { dn: 'the-resolved-dn' }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // login failed
  }
  else {
    // login successful
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet at the moment is to look through the code in https://github.com/emgee3/meteor-accounts-ldap and try to adapt it for your own purposes.